# Не работают библеотеки UE4

Tags: c++, include, unreal-engine-4

Всем привет! Сносил Windows, проект UE4 загрузил на google диск, потом скачал, установил все пакеты redistructable c++, visual studio и тд. Версия движка та же. На скрине вся та фигня что мне высвечивает, говорит что не может найти файлы. Пробовал пересобирать решение, очищать решение, не работает. Плюс выдаёт ошибку:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(38,5): error MSB3073: выход из команды "A:\UE_4.27\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Clean.bat TopDownShooter_SBEditor Win64 Development -Project="D:\UE Projects\TopDownShooter_SB\TopDownShooter_SB.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" с кодом 3.
```

Где `TopDownShooter_SB` - название проекта Что делать?

[image: вот тут пример]

Comment: ¿Пути установки UE и/или Vs случаем не поменялись?

Comment: Скорее всего поменялись, точнее visual studio